# Extracting plus 4 zip code from geocoding using google API, jQuery

Tags: jquery, geocoding, street-address

I am using Geo coding using google API with the help of jQuery. The following is the code i tried.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
jQuery('AddressPicker1').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode({ address: request.term}, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          response(jQuery.map(results, function(item) {
          var streetNumber = "";
          var streetName = "";
          var cityName = "";
          var zip = "";
          var country = "";
          var countyName = "";
          var state = "";  

          for ( var component =0; component < item.address_components.length; component++ ) {
             if (item.address_components[component] != undefined && item.address_components[component] != null ) {
                  if ( jQuery.inArray("street_number", item.address_components[component].types) > -1 ){
                      streetNumber = item.address_components[component].long_name;
                  }

                  if ( jQuery.inArray("route", item.address_components[component].types) > -1){
                      streetName = item.address_components[component].long_name;
                  }

                  if ( jQuery.inArray("locality", item.address_components[component].types) > -1){
                      cityName = item.address_components[component].long_name;
                  }

                  if ( jQuery.inArray("postal_code", item.address_components[component].types) > -1){
                      zip = item.address_components[component].long_name;
                  }

                  if ( jQuery.inArray("country", item.address_components[component].types) > -1){
                      country = item.address_components[component].long_name;
                  }

                  if ( jQuery.inArray("administrative_area_level_2", item.address_components[component].types) > -1){
                        countyName = item.address_components[component].long_name;
                  }

                  if ( jQuery.inArray("administrative_area_level_1", item.address_components[component].types) > -1){
                        state = item.address_components[component].short_name; 
                  }
            }
          }
    return {
        label : item.formatted_address,
        value : item.formatted_address,
        latitude : item.geometry.location.lat(),
        longitude : item.geometry.location.lng(),
        streetNo : streetNumber,
        streetName : streetName,
        city : cityName.toUpperCase() ,
        zip : zip,
        country : country,
        county : countyName.toUpperCase(),
        state : state
    }

     }));
   }
 });
 },
 select: function (event, ui) {
      jQuery('StreetNumber').val(ui.item.streetNo);
      jQuery('StreetName').val(ui.item.streetName);
      jQuery('City').val(ui.item.city);
      jQuery('Zip').val(ui.item.zip);
      jQuery('Country').val(ui.item.country);
      jQuery('CountyName').val(ui.item.county);
      jQuery('StateCode').val(ui.item.state);
      jQuery('GeocodedLatitude').val(ui.item.latitude);
      jQuery('GeocodedLongitude').val(ui.item.longitude);

 }
```

I faced the problem during searching plus 4 zip codes. i didn't get additional 4 digits in the response.
Example ,For the search text, "60 MAIN ST,HUNTINGTON NY 11743-6961". 
I retrieved the '11743' through 'postal_code' attribute in the response. But i cant able to retrieve '6961' from the response.

Is there any options to get the full zip code in this scenario?

or I need to try for some other way to search plus 4 zip code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Google's geocoder doesn't append ZIP +4 (addon) codes.

Google doesn't verify addresses, which includes standardizing its format, which in turn includes appending the ZIP+4 code.

What you probably need is an API that actually standardizes and validates addresses. An API like [LiveAddress](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) will probably do what you want. It will return all the address components, including the +4 addon code.

I'm a developer at SmartyStreets. Here's an example of a response for the address you give in your question, with the +4 code you use -- there are actually two +4 codes at this delivery point because one is the firm, the YMCA, and I'll just show the one here:

```
{
    "input_index": 0,
    "candidate_index": 1,
    "addressee": "Ymca",
    "delivery_line_1": "60 Main St",
    "last_line": "Huntington NY 11743-6961",
    "delivery_point_barcode": "117436961606",
    "components": {
        "primary_number": "60",
        "street_name": "Main",
        "street_suffix": "St",
        "city_name": "Huntington",
        "state_abbreviation": "NY",
        "zipcode": "11743",
        "plus4_code": "6961",
        "delivery_point": "60",
        "delivery_point_check_digit": "6"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "record_type": "F",
        "county_fips": "36103",
        "county_name": "Suffolk",
        "carrier_route": "C037",
        "congressional_district": "03",
        "rdi": "Commercial",
        "latitude": 40.87179,
        "longitude": -73.42655,
        "precision": "Zip7"
    },
    "analysis": {
        "dpv_match_code": "Y",
        "dpv_footnotes": "AABB",
        "dpv_cmra": "N",
        "dpv_vacant": "N",
        "active": "Y"
    }
}
```

Here's the lookup on the SmartyStreets homepage with full results: http://smartystreets.com/?street=60%20Main%20St&city=Huntington&state=NY&zipcode=11743

Anyway, this is the difference been address validation and geocoding. Geocoding merely turns an address into coordinates, but if you need the +4 code, you need an address validation API. LiveAddress is one of a few you can use, but this should give you a better idea and you can start your search there.

Comment: yes Matt. You're right. I will check about LiveAddress API. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

Use google place API's [details request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details). If found, the +4 zip code will be returned as an address component of type "postal_code_suffix".

### Long Version

Google place API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) is not particularly helpful in explaining what address component type to use. Searching for the given address without the +4 code via google place API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=60 MAIN ST,HUNTINGTON NY 11743&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id&key=<KEY>
```

Gives place ID `ChIJYWl9Uism6IkRtW81pi9SvgM`.

I can then use a place details request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJYWl9Uism6IkRtW81pi9SvgM&key=<KEY>
```

This shows a full postcode in the `adr_address` property: `...<span class=\"postal-code\">11743-8003</span>...`. Note that the +4 zip code has likely changed since this SO question was posted (yes, +4 zip codes can change frequently!). This info is more conveniently returned as an address component with type  `postal_code_suffix` in the response:

```
...
results: {
  ...
  address_components: [
    ...
    { long_name: "8003"
    , short_name: "8003"
    , types: ["postal_code_suffix"]
    }
    ...
  ]
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: `*If found` clause implies it isn't reliable for fetching +4 zip code.